# How to get Sqlite heap usage using Xerial JDBC?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

We are using Xerial JDBC 3.36.0.2 which seems to be [compiled](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/3.36.0.2/Makefile#L85) with
-DSQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS=0 thereby disabling memory status interface.

I wanted to track the heap usage(SQLITE_STATUS_MEMORY_USED) and page cache used per connection(SQLITE_DBSTATUS_CACHE_USED) but seems this would not work.

My understanding is any extension(like memstat) won't work either as they all need Sqlite's MEMSTATUS flag to be enabled at compile time.

Is there a way to get these stats in Xerial JDBC?